# Determine why SSL verification fails on some networks

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I want to find a reason why my SSL is not working on some networks or at least guide me to the correct path.

So I have a domain `example.com` and multiple subdomains `abc.example.com`, `def.example.com`, and a wildcard SSL for `*.example.com`.

Recently I faced this strange behavior which is when I open a new browser (or a new incognito tab) and go directly to `abc.example.com` it gives me the error `Your connection is not private NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`. But other domains (`def.example.com`, `example.com`) are working fine.
I found out that when I refresh the page/or visit `abc.example.com` after `exmaple.com` it works fine.

but this error happens only in a few networks.

When I see the certificate of errored page, it shows completely different organization/ CA:

```
Organization (O)            Fortinet
Organizational Unit (OU)    Certificate Authority
```

here is some info on certificate of the working version:

```
Common Name (CN)            GTS CA 1P5
Organization (O)            Google Trust Services LLC
Organizational Unit (OU)    <Not Part Of Certificate>
```

And when I try `openssl s_client -connect abc.example.com:443`:

```
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
```

but `openssl s_client -connect def.example.com:443`:
`Verify return code: 0 (ok)`

I just need to know how to fix it or at least why or when it could happen. Thank you.